# Wiring an automatic solar light for a tiny library

Tags: circuit-design, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller, circuits

I want to add a light that comes on when you open the door to my tiny library that's powered by a small solar panel. I'm no electrical expert but I do know basics enough to make simple circuits.

My original idea was to cannibalize one of those cheap garden solar lights that come on when it's dark out and then run it through a normally open switch attached to the door. My problem is that the lights I want to use run off 12v and the output of the little circuit board is around 1.5. I tried running a voltage booster circuit off the output of where the LED from the garden light was, but for some reason it won't register anything on the output side of the booster.

Does anyone know an easy (and more importantly cheap) way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: The solar light you took apart is only producing a few mA at 3V like a joule thief. A step up boost circuit already. Trying to add a regulator to that and drawing a watt isn't going to work. You need a bigger driver. Plenty of circuit examples online. How much current do you need?

Comment: Do you read books only during the day?

Comment: You will need a 12 volt battery and a much larger solar panel designed to charge a 12 volt battery.

Comment: I'm not sure how much current the lights draw, my whole idea behind this project is to not spend any money. I was hoping to get away with the lower volt charger and not a 12v system because the lights won't be continuously on, only maybe 30 seconds per night

Comment: If you look at the datasheet for the booster I think you will find your challenge (1.5 volt)

Comment: you can't do it with "one of those cheap garden solar lights", but you can do it well (12v, decent current) with 10 of them by wiring all the batteries in series. Don't connect to the output, connect to the batteries directly, and use the solar to charge (the batteries can't normally "see" each other to interfere with one another). you could also get 5v lights, say a cheap USB light, then you only need 4 solar lights instead of 10 (1.2v*4=4.8v, close enough). Cut out the solar light's LED so that it doesn't waste energy.

Comment: You can use a 12V wall wart, NPN transistor and a resistor to accomplish what you want with an additional power source.  Why not consider a PIR powered from the mains to control the light. if it comes on in the day does it really matter. Some lights even have them built in.  You can use a set of burglar (magnet) alarm switch to detect the door open. Sad part none of these is solar powered but you will have light.